# Return value format of stream_get_meta_data() in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple PHP script, but I found a strange behavior (not a bug): the format of return value of stream_get_meta_data() is not consistent on different platforms.

Simplified sample code is listed below:

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("http://www.example.com", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $dump = fgets($handle);
        $stream_meta = stream_get_meta_data( $handle );
        echo print_r( $stream_meta, true );
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

This PHP script is supposed to run on my QNAP TS-269 NAS. As everyone else would do, I wrote and test code on my PC and then move to NAS.

When I execute this code on my PC, I get this result:

```
Array
(
    [timed_out] => 
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] => 
    [wrapper_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
            [1] => Cache-Control: max-age=604800
            [2] => Content-Type: text/html
            [3] => Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2017 08:44:14 GMT
            [4] => Etag: "359670651+ident"
            [5] => Expires: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 08:44:14 GMT
            [6] => Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
            [7] => Server: ECS (rhv/818F)
            [8] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
            [9] => X-Cache: HIT
            [10] => x-ec-custom-error: 1
            [11] => Content-Length: 1270
            [12] => Connection: close
        )

    [wrapper_type] => http
    [stream_type] => tcp_socket/ssl
    [mode] => r
    [unread_bytes] => 1254
    [seekable] => 
    [uri] => http://www.example.com
)
```

But on NAS the result becomes:

```
Array
(
    [wrapper_data] => Array
        (
            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    [1] => Cache-Control: max-age=604800
                    [2] => Content-Type: text/html
                    [3] => Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2017 08:44:25 GMT
                    [4] => Etag: "359670651+ident"
                    [5] => Expires: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 08:44:25 GMT
                    [6] => Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
                    [7] => Server: ECS (rhv/818F)
                    [8] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
                    [9] => X-Cache: HIT
                    [10] => x-ec-custom-error: 1
                    [11] => Content-Length: 1270
                )

            [readbuf] => Resource id #6
        )

    [wrapper_type] => cURL
    [stream_type] => cURL
    [mode] => r
    [unread_bytes] => 1254
    [seekable] => 
    [uri] => http://www.example.com
    [timed_out] => 
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] => 
)
```

The array structure of `$result['wrapper_data']` is different. The first result (on PC) matches with examples on PHP official website. On NAS these HTTP response headers are collected under an extra level `$result['wrapper_data']['header']`.

The PHP version is 5.6.28 on PC, 5.3.29 on NAS.

Is that a normal behavior ? Due to different PHP version or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you have two different wrappers (the 'wrapper_type' field): http on your PC, and cURL on NAS. Maybe you run your script as Apache module in one case, and in CLI mode in the other case?

UPD:
http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php
"Beginning with PHP 4.3.0 you can configure PHP to use cURL for URL streams --with-curlwrappers. This feature was moved to PECL as of PHP 5.5.0"

Comment: No, I'm running script in CLI mode on both machines. Is there a php.ini settings or something so that I can change wrapper ? cURL wrapper does not work as expected in many ways. For example, the $http_response_header variable will not be set after fopen() when using cURL wrapper, until fgets() or fread() is called.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment. Please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163589/338114) to understand when to post an answer and when to post a comment.

Comment: I haven't enough reputation to comment question

Comment: @RichardLiu I think, it is
--with-curlwrappers
compile-time flag. Please, refer to http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php